# Mysql AFTER INSERT syntax error when calling previously inserted variable

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger **after a comment is inserted** on the "**comment**" table, the trigger **updates the total of comments** on the "**post**" table based on the post id of the inserted comment.
The trigger is returning an error and I don't even know where to begin to solve this problem.
The error says something's wrong on the "UPDATE" line.
The tables "**post**" and "**comment**" have the common column name "**post_id**".
Here is the trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_post_comments
AFTER INSERT 
ON `comment` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE `post` 
    SET total_comments = (total_comments +1)
    WHERE post_id = new.post_id;
END
```

**Error message:**
[image]

| Here is the database tables definition: |
| --- |
| comment table |
| [image] |
| post table |
| [image] |

I looked up similar questions but I didn't find a solution, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: There is no comments column in the posts table link..also are you setting delimiters?

Comment: 'are they needed' - try it and see.

Comment: The best way to post table structure is by copying the result of this query `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` into your question and certainly not as images. Even the error message you should just post as texts instead of image.

Comment: Why do you need `\`` sign for table names like `\`comment\``. You can do it without that sign, see [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: [Works for Me ™](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78284c3f5248f45ca6b2da3165d14323)

Comment: Adding the delimiter solved the problem, thank you @P.Salmon